# iPad, how to lock app on front of screen?

Tags: ios, locking, homescreen

I have an webpage with some forms opened in Safari browser. Some customers will type in some data and send forms.

I need block home button (and others buttons too) that customer will not able switch to another app and this app will be always front of the screen.

Exist for this some app or something similar?

I'm also interested in case that i have my own app with same forms.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Guided Access on the iPad to keep it locked to that one application, that's in Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access Look at this for more details http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US